# installing yui compressor for django pipeline

Tags: python, django, compression, yui-compressor

I'm trying to use django pipeline, should be able to get it working but I'm just unsure as to how to install yui compressor on my system so pipeline recognizes it?

Answer (score 1):

You can [download](http://yuilibrary.com/download/yuicompressor/) it and install manually or you can use your system package manager (e.g. in Debian: `sudo apt-get install yui-compressor`). After that you need to point binary in your settings:

```
PIPELINE_YUI_BINARY = '<path to yuicompressor>'
```